# Basic digital circuit questions about counters and shift registers

Tags: digital-logic

Is there any way that we take a shift register and turn it into a counter? Or they are complete different things?

Comment: Depends how much disconnecting and rewiring you can do around the shift register. They are both made using flip flops. See also "Johnson counter".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a shift register can be used as a "counter" in the sense that a shift register, if wired correctly, will have some number of distinct states and deterministic behavior.